# How to get more Feed items? xcode

Tags: xcode, rss, feed

How would I get the next page or more results for a feed?
Google Reader does not work
What are the alternatives?

PS: I use RSSItem.h and UIImageView+AFNetworking.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check http://superfeedr.com for an alternative to Google Reader.